# Excel get data with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, ms-office, vlookup

I have a table with data like this

[image]

How to insert value to C10 base on A10&B10?
And C11 base on A11 & B11 too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple INDEX/MATCH/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(A10,B:B,0),MATCH(B10,$2:$2,0))
```

Comment: One more question, if I have SUM(C3:D3), SUM(C4:D4), .... SUM(Cn:Dn), how to count the number of rows that have largest sum ?

Comment: That is a new question and should have its own post.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to insert an if function into your vlookup.

```
VLOOKUP(A10,B3:D6,IF(B10="x",2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula to get the desired result:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($A$10,$B:$B,0),MATCH($B$10,$2:$2,0)))
```